# AHK can't load all html

Tags: html, autohotkey

I have the following code to change one frame in the webpage and it works fine.

```
    fr1 :=IE.document.frames[13]
    fr1.navigate("http blablabla ")
```

then I need to parse one of the tables in that page. Unfortunately, even though I see all the info in the browser, the HTML of the page seems to be incomplete and the table in question can't be found. In fact, I tried

```
    test := fr1.document
    FileAppend,%test%,%A_ScriptDir%\Test.txt
```

the file Test.txt is different from what I find when right clicking the webpage in the browser and inspect element and is missing that table I need.

how do i find the whole html?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
test := fr1.document
```

to

```
test := IE.document.frames[13].document
```

Also, check if maybe the table you need is in a nested Iframe.

Comment: Nothing changes. But there are iframes. How do I deal with them?

Comment: Can you send the HTML of the page, or share the link of the page you are trying to open.